# Can you use a for loop inside the condition of an if-else statement?

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop

Can you use a for loop inside the condition of an `if-else` statement? For example, something like this...

```
if(
        for(q = 0; q < 10; q++){
            values[q]>=values[q+1];
        }          
            )

            {

         done = 0;
    }
```

This is loading an error I can't seem to place. I want the if statement to check to see if the `int[]` I called `values` is in order from greatest to least, and if it is, set `int` variable `done` equal to 0.

I only just started taking a programming class and I bet this is a very dumb mistake, but I've been trying to figure this out for a while and some help would be absolutely fantastic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should work out your condition first (ie is your array in order), and then feed that in to your `if` statement. Like so...

```
boolean isOrdered = true;

for(q = 0; q < 10; q++){
  if (values[q]>=values[q+1]){
    // in order
    }
  else {
    // not in order
    isOrdered = false;
    break; // we have found a false, so we can quit out of the for loop
    }
  }

if (isOrdered){
  // do something if the array is in order;
  }
```

Comment: No problem. If you like the answer, please 'tick' it to let everyone know that your problem has been solved.

Comment: if he implements your code he will have more problems.

Comment: @user2310289 such as...?

Comment: what happens if all values in order (values[q+1])?

Comment: @WATTO Your code is logically correct but you need to change your for loop condition to `q < 9`. On your for loop's last iteration, values[q] >= values[q+1] will throw an ArrayIndexBoundsException error.

Comment: @user2310289 that piece of code is taken from the OPs example. I agree that this statement could be written better, but I wanted to show the OPs code in my answer for their learning, which is what they wanted.

Comment: @davecroman additionally to my above comment, is it not possible that the OP has already taken this in to consideration in their code - ie their array actually has 11 elements in it. My aim was to answer to assist the OPs learning, which is what they asked for, so I stand by my reasoning for using their code in my answer.

Comment: @WATTO Point taken. Touche! :)

Comment: To clear this up, this is a piece of a longer code (removing the second largest element from an int[]), I just wanted to figure out what was wrong with what I was doing conceptually so I tried to make it as simple as possible here. Now I understand what was wrong with it and I feel properly silly about not getting it in the first place. All's well! And thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You can do it if you refactor the logic into a method that returns a boolean:

```
if (isInOrder(values)) {
    //
}

private static boolean isInOrder(int[] array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++)
        if (array[i] > array[i+1])
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A for loop **can** exist inside of an if block

```
if (true) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World!");
    }
}
```

But a for loop can **not** be the condition of the if block

```
if( for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { } ) { }
```

A for loop is not a boolean. Every if condition requires a boolean.

Comment: can `if` be inside a `for` loop condition

Comment: @vikrant The condition for a `for` loop must be boolean. An if statement is not a boolean.

Answer (score 1):

**No**. `If` requires a **boolean** test. `For loop` doesn't return a boolean value. You can instead separate the check into another function.

```
if( isArrayOrdered(values) ){
    done = 0;
}

// assuming values is an array of `int` values
private boolean isArrayOrdered( int[] values){
   for(int q = 1; q < values.length; q++){ 

      if( values[q] > values[q-1] ){
         return false;
      }
   }

   return true;
}
```

Comment: Can we return a string instead of a boolean? Will it work?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. The `if` condition must evaluate to some boolean value, which doesn't happen with this `for` loop.

It can only be in the `if` statement body, like

```
if(someCondition)
    for(int i = 0;i < 10;i++)...
```

To achieve your goal, a code like this one might help:

```
boolean ordered = true;

for(int i = 0;i < array.length - 1;i++) {
    if(array[i] > array[i+1]) {
        ordered = false;
        break;
    }
}

if(ordered) // your if body here
```

Comment: If I was able to have the statement return true would that fix the problem?

Comment: @user3413468 what exactly are you trying to achieve? You can't `return true` inside an `if` condition.

Answer (score 0):

The expression inside the "if" condition should evaluate to a boolean or Boolean otherwise the code will not compile.

Check that Java specs page [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.9)

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably want the alternate nesting, and start with the assumption that `done = 0` (that is, that the list is correctly ordered), unless you prove in the loop that it is not true.

```
public class Play{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        done = 0;
        for(q = 1; q < 10; q++){
            if (values[q-1]<values[q]) {
                  done = 1;
                  break;
             }   

        }          


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to break you logic down into steps.

first of all, a method

```
boolean isInOrder (int [] values) {

    for(int q = 0; q < values.length - 1; q++){

        if (values[q] > values[q+1]) {
          return false; 
        }
   }
   return true;
}
```

// now lets call this method

```
  if (isInOrder (values)) {
     System.out.println ("In Order");
  }
  else {
     System.out.println ("Not In Order");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to put the "for loop" statement between if statement "(" and ")".But it is possible if you write "for loop" between if statement "{" and "}".Thanks